# Could the JVM load a dynamic LIBRARY from network？if could be and how？ THANKS

Tags: java, dynamic-library

Could the JVM load a dynamic LIBRARY from network？if could be and how？ THANKS

I am studying JNI recently.

I am working wiht mates, when other mates developing in theirs environment, they haven't the *.dll(so.*)  file. And i do not want to send the file individually.

Comment: does this help? https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/classloaders.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the JVM can send and receive files across the network, and  the `System.load` method can load DLL files from disk.